# Error when creating 2D slice

Tags: go

I am trying to create and initialize a 2D slice in Go. While the following function works without any issues:

```
func working2D() [][]uint8 {
    p := make([][]uint8, 2)
    for i:=range p{
        p[i]=make([]uint8, 8)
        for j:=range p[i]{
            p[i][j]=uint8(j)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(p)
    return p
}
```

> Output: [[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7] [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]]

But the following function does not even compile and throws a compilation error:

> sample/main/range.go:35:9: v2 declared and not used

```
func notWorking2D() [][]uint8 {
    p := make([][]uint8, 1)
    for _,v := range p {
        v = make([]uint8, 8)
        for j, v2 := range v {
            v2 = uint8(j)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(p)
    return p
}
```

> Output: [[],[]]

What is it that I am missing in the second function?

Comment: The second variable in a `range` gets set to each value in the slice as the loop iterates. Assigning to that variable does not affect the slice.

Comment: thanks for the clarification @AndySchweig.

Answer (score 1):

As Andy said in a comment:

> The second variable in a range gets set to each value in the slice as the loop iterates. Assigning to that variable does not affect the slice.

You probably just want to do:

```
func notWorking2D() [][]uint8 {
    p := make([][]uint8, 2)
    for i, _ := range p {      
        p[i] = make([]uint8, 8)
        for j, _ := range p[i] {
            p[i][j] = uint8(j)
        }
    }
    return p
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/cHQc9ReJBE

Comment: Thanks for your time dave. Yes, Andy had answered my question

Answer (score 0):

There’ re no 2d slice in Go.

You can create a “slice of slices”. This has drawback as you have to initialize every “subslice” manually.

Also gives toy more flexibility as any particular slice can have its own length and capacity.

```
func slice2(n int) [][]int {
    Result := make([][]int, 0, n)
    for i:=0; i<n; i++ {
        Result = append(Result, make([]int))
    }
    return Result
}
```